# Of n coin flips, at most p*n are heads - estimate

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Given number $0<p<1$, I want to compute for any integer $n>0$ the probability that at most $p\cdot n$ coins are head. I know that I can sum

$${n \choose 0} + {n \choose 1} + \ldots + {n \choose \lfloor p\cdot n \rfloor}$$

and divide it by $2^n$. But I am interested in a more "direct" estimate, from which I can see (for fixed $p$), how this number evolves with growing $n$.

Comment: the coin is fair ?

Comment: Are you looking for a closed expression for the binomial sum or for its asymptotic for large $n$?

Comment: @Youem The coin is fair.

Comment: @user Both would be useful, but I am mostly interested in the (negative) growth of this expression with respect to $n$.

Comment: For $p = 1/2$, and any _odd_ $n$, your sum is exactly one half of the total possibilities, i.e. $2^{n-1}$.  For even $n$ your sum is slightly larger than that, by ${n \choose n/2} / 2$ because you include the entire middle term while one half would include just half of the middle term.

Comment: See  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93744/estimating-a-partial-sum-of-weighted-binomial-coefficients/93750#93750